# Why can LINQ operations be faster than a normal loop?

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, performance, sorting

A friend and I were a bit perplexed during a programming discussion today. As an example, we created a fictive problem of having a `List<int>` of n random integers (typically 1.000.000) and wanted to create a function that returned the set of all integers that there were more than one of. Pretty straightforward stuff. We created one LINQ statement to solve this problem, and a plain insertion sort based algorithm.

Now, as we tested the speed the code ran at (using `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`), the results were confusing. Not only did the LINQ code outperform the simple sort, but it ran faster than *a single* `foreach`/`for` that only did a single loop of the list, and that had no operations within (which, on a side track, I thought the compiler was supposed to discover and remove alltogether).

If we generated a new `List<int>` of random numbers in the same execution of the program and ran the LINQ code again, the performance would increase by orders of magnitude (typically thousandfold). The performance of the empty loops were of course the same.

So, what is going on here? Is LINQ using parallelism to outperform normal loops? How are these results even possible? LINQ uses quicksort which runs at n*log(n), which per definition is already slower than n.

And what is happening at the performance leap on the second run?

We were both baffled and intrigued at these results and were hoping for some clarifying insights from the community, just to satisfy our own curiosity.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your test?

Comment: Post your code.  You are probably not considering [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing that code and playing with this myself... but the fact that you say it even outperforms an empty loop strongly suggests you not be stopwatching at the correct places in the code, as per Matthew Flaschen's comment.

Comment: The code is only a few lines long so there aren't even much room to go wrong even if we intended to. But I'll have to post this code tomorrow since I don't have the project here at my home computer.

Comment: "Linq uses quicksort which runs at n*log(n), which per definition is already slower than n."  Not true.  n*log(n) is *asymptotically* slower than n, but the constant factors can create a case where, in practice, an n*log(n) algorithm is faster than a linear algorithm on certain datasets.

Comment: Technically correct, but there are no hidden agendas or advanced code here. 1) Outside performance test: create big random dataset. 2a) Inside performance test: execute linq on the dataset. 2b) Inside a second performance test: run a for-loop over the dataset. Not anymore complicated than that. Hence our grave puzzledness.

Comment: There are some good comments on the possibilities but I'll have to defer judgement until I see the code and try it out. :)

Comment: Related reading: http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/11/19/an-easy-and-efficient-way-to-improve-net-code-performances.aspx and http://diditwith.net/PermaLink,guid,506c0888-8c5f-40e5-9d39-a09e2ebf3a55.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Undoubtedly you haven't actually performed the query, you've merely defined it.  LINQ constructs an expression tree that isn't actually evaluated until you perform an operation that requires that the enumeration be iterated.  Try adding a `ToList()` or `Count()` operation to the LINQ query to force the query to be evaluated.

Based on your comment I expect this is similar to what you've done.  Note: I haven't spent any time figuring out if the query is as efficient as possible; I just want *some* query to illustrate how the code may be structured.

```
var dataset = ...

var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var query = dataset.Where( d => dataset.Count( i => i == d ) > 1 );

watch.Stop();  // timer stops here

foreach (var item in query) // query is actually evaluated here
{
   ... print out the item...
}
```

Comment: Negatory: We printed the dataset to verify that it was actually doing what it was doing.

Comment: @Pedery -- but did you print it out from within the timed code section or outside it.  Iterating over it to print it would cause it to be evaluated, but if you didn't time the loop where it was printed the evaluation would have been done outside the timing loop.

Comment: We assigned the result of the linq to a var, then printed it outside the timed area.

Comment: Yep, I see your edit. Regarding performance and the timer, your example is analoguous to our code. I think this explains the issue.

Comment: Please see the plethora of topics on "deferred execution" and Linq.  These are exposed in both IEnumerable<T> (DataSet.Where, et. Al) and IQueryable<T> (for entities and Linq-to-Sql).  The advantage is building a large Linq query without touching the objects that you are querying until absolutely needed for retrieval (the foreach var item portion of the code).  At that point an enumerator is built on the resulting collection from the query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that LINQ is only faster than a 'normal loop' when your algorithm is less than perfect (or you have some problem in your code).  So LINQ will be faster at sorting than you are if you don't write an efficient sorting algorithm, etc.

LINQ is usually 'as fast as' or 'close enough to' the speed of a normal loop, and can be faster (and simpler) to code / debug / read.  That's its benefit - not execution speed.

If it's performing faster than an empty loop, you are doing something wrong.  Most likely, as suggested in comments, you aren't considering deferred execution and the LINQ statement is not actually executing.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, we printed the dataset it was producing and all seemed to be in order.

Comment: You would have to print it before the stopwatch stopped.  Printing is too slow, however - best is to dump it into a List.

Comment: Hehe, comparing anything I write to anything found in the BCL, yes, all of my code is less then perfect. :O

Answer (score 1):

If you did not compile with "Optimize Code" enabled, you would probably see this behaviour. (It would certainly explain why the empty loop was not removed.)

The code underlying LINQ, however, is part of already-compiled code, which will certainly have been optimised (by the JIT, [NGen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Image_Generator) or similar).

Comment: +1 Good point! I forgot to check the computer's VS default settings regarding code optimizing.